# Fourth CDockablePane does not size correctly

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Single-Document MFC project that I am implementing using Visual Studio 2008.

Here is an image of the problem I am having. This image has been redacted for your safety.

[image: An image with four panes]

If the image doesn't load in your web-browser, here is a ASCII rendering of it:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Pane 1 |    Pane 2    | Pane 3 | P | (Pane 4 is |
|        |              |        | a | too small  |
|        |              |        | n | no matter  |
|        |              |        | e | what width |
|        |              |        | 4 | I give it.)|
|        |              |        |   |            |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The three left-most panes size correctly just fine, but the fourth pane comes out the same (incorrect) size no matter what width I give it.

Here is what my `CMainFrame::OnCreate()` looks like:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    // Omitting lots of automatically generated code here

    if (this->InitMyPane1 () == FALSE) {
        return -1 ;
    }

    if (this->InitMyPane2 () == FALSE) {
        return -1 ;
    }

    if (this->InitMyPane3 () == FALSE) {
        return -1 ;
    }

    if (this->InitMyPane4 () == FALSE) {
        return -1 ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code for all of these `InitMyPaneX()` functions is very similar. It is the `InitMyPane4 ()` that seems to be producing the incorrect results.

```
BOOL CMainFrame::InitMyPane4 ()
{
    CRect rect ;
    this->GetClientRect (&rect) ;

    int right = static_cast <int> (rect.Width () / 6) ;
    int bottom = rect.Height () ;

    DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_ALIGN_LEFT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI ;

    BOOL bOk = m_MyPane4.Create (
        _T ("My Pane 4"), this, 
        CRect (0, 0, right, bottom), TRUE, IDC_MY_PANE_4, dwStyle
    ) ;

    if (bOk == FALSE) {
        return FALSE ;
    }

    m_MyPane4.EnableDocking (CBRS_ALIGN_ANY) ;
    this->DockPane ((CBasePane *) &m_MyPane4, AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_LEFT) ;
    this->RecalcLayout () ;

    return bOk ;
}
```

The `right` variable in the code above is what should be modifying the width of the pane, but it seems to have no affect no matter what value I give it.

What could be causing MFC to not size the pane correctly?

**UPDATE**

It seems to size correctly as long as `right <= 200`. If I try to increase the size after that, nothing happens.

If I make the size really small (~10), I can see some strange divider appear.
The pane does not seem to want to grow in size past this divider.
I'm not sure where this divider came from or how to get rid of it.

[image: Strange divider]

Comment: Why are you dividing the width by 6?

Comment: @rrirower Before trying to get the math right to have it fill up the entire freespace remaining, I wanted to see if I could at least give it the same size as Panes 1 and 3. Unfortunately, it doesn't change sizes no matter what width I give it.

Comment: Have you tried debugging into RecalcLayout?

Comment: @rrirower That is a function that is automatically provided by MFC.

Comment: I am aware of that.  And, that won't prevent you from stepping through the code for RecalcLayout.  Stepping through that code may provide some insight as to why the sizing is incorrect.

Comment: @rrirower I just stepped through `RecalcLayout()` on a correctly sizing pane and the incorrectly sizing pane. They followed the same path of execution. I still think this has something to do with that divider that I mentioned, but I'll try to step into the functions within `RecalcLayout()` later and see where there are any differences.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem in that Panel4 is too small, try the `SetMinSize(...)` function on it

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work. I'm almost certain the problem has to do with the pane divider.

Comment: I have this function working for me in 4 of my panes on a mainframe that has many more. Maybe your window is too small, or the conjugation between all panes can not give that width to it.